# SQL, Oracle NULL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this bit of code in my query, when I remove it then it works fine, if I keep it in I get a

> "ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword"

message.

```
CASE WHEN pp.phone_number is '0' THEN ''
```

I have other When - Then and an END statement in there so it's not that.

The whole code, in case you wanted to see is:

```
CASE WHEN pp.country_code_number = 44 THEN '0'||SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', ''),-10) 
                WHEN pp.country_code_number IS NULL THEN '0'||SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(pp.phone_number, '[^0-9]+', ''),-10) 
                WHEN pp.phone_number is '0' THEN ''
                WHEN pp.phone_number is NULL THEN 'Blank'
                ELSE '***ERROR***'
                END
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IS` is only used to check `NULL`; for example

```
CASE WHEN pp.phone_number IS NULL THEN …
```

What you need is:

```
CASE WHEN pp.phone_number = '0' THEN ''
…
```

As an aside, you are using a string (`'0'`) that looks like a number; maybe you need to check your types.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted so far, should be `=`, not `is`:

```
case when pp.phone_number = '0' then ''
```

is is used for NULLs, e.g. `is null` or `is not null`